# Como renomear vários arquivos do input file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como alterar o nome dos arquivos que vão para um determinado diretório ?
Esse é meu código;

```
$upload_files = $_FILES['files'];  

                // Inicia o array dos dados que serão inseridos
                $conf2 = array();

                // Varre o array com info. dos arquivos
                for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($upload_files); $i++) {

                    // Nome do arquivo em cada elemento
                    $new_name = $upload_files[$i]['name'];


                    //Configure upload.
                    $conf2[] = array(
                        "file_name" => $new_name,
                        "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/'. $past_date .'/'. $pasta .'/',
                        "allowed_types" => "mp3",
                        "max_size"  => "2194304000"
                    );

                    $this->upload->initialize($conf2);              
                }
```

Estou usando a classe [CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload](https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload)

Comment: Está usando o Codeiginter?

Comment: Sim, com a class de multiplo upload MY_upload

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, renomear somente os arquivos que vão para um diretório específico?

Comment: Você não pode "renomear os arquivos do input file", mas sim salvar o upload dos mesmos com um novo nome. No caso, bastaria você pegar a extensão do arquivo com a função [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php) e criar um novo nome, concatenando com a extensão detectada pela função `pathinfo`